# What are the predefined single-character variables in python called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, undefined

My point is that python has some predefined variables that you may have not even set, but still was given a value when you start off the shell. Say you ran the following code:

```
print (a)
```

Without even having defined variable "a" beforehand, it returned 0. Wherease, if you tried printing:

```
print(var1)
```

Would return an error because var1 was not defined. I did a bit of testing and found out the same goes for every other single character in python, print any of them out on the console and you will get the same result of 0.

The question I'd like to ask is that why are these characters given their own value beforehand? And are there special names for these predefined variables such as these? If I could know the name of these special variables, I could read upon some documentations about them.

Comment: Running `print(a)` on its own does not return `0` unless you've previously set `a=0`.

Comment: There are no such "predefined variables", `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` and similar will occur for any variable which you did not create.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you don't have that defined somewhere?

Comment: You *do* have a set of built-in names, e.g `print`, `max`, `int` etc. `a` is not one of them.

Comment: oh... you guys are right! - This is strange, I swear I was able to print out all the single character and got 0 for all of them. When I reset my console - now it gave me an error instead

Answer (score 2):

There are no predefined variables in python.

```
print(a)
```

will return `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` as long as `a` has not been defined earlier.